# if condition in visualforce

Tags: visualforce, conditional

I am new to salesforce, apex and vf so please bear with me. Below is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function updateSplash(){
  UpdateUser();
}        
</script>
<apex:actionFunction name="UpdateUser" action="{!updateDSMTracker}" rerender="" >
  <apex:param assignTo="{!UserId}" name="UserId" value="{!$User.Id}"/>
</apex:actionFunction>
```

but I only want to include this piece of code  in my page conditionally. For example:

```
if (showColorbox == true){
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function updateSplash(){
      UpdateUser();
    }
  </script>
  <apex:actionFunction name="UpdateUser" action="{!updateDSMTracker}" rerender="" >
    <apex:param assignTo="{!UserId}" name="UserId" value="{!$User.Id}"/>
  </apex:actionFunction>
}
```

where showColorbox is an apex boolean variable and if it is true then only it should include this
javascript function and vf piece otherwise not. But I am unable to find any help on this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by using `rendered` option. Example of how to do it:

```
<apex:panelGroup rendered="{!myCondition}">
  <!-- the rest of the code that should only be rendered(visible) if "myCondition" is true -->
</apex:panelGroup>
```

*myCondition* must be a boolean, but not necessarily a boolean variable. It could be a simple comparison, for example:

```
<apex:panelGroup rendered="{!myInteger == 3}">
  <!-- then I will only see this if value of "myInteger" variable is 3 -->
</apex:panelGroup>
```

Comment: I would suggest you put your content in an outputPanel instead. That way you have the lightest possible DOM. Or, if this is something you want to use in multiple pages, create a Visualforce Component.